# VirtualBox: Failed to perform an online medium merge (VERR_DISK_FULL)

Tags: virtualbox, linux-mint, disk-space

I'm running a Windows VM on a 128GB SSD. I allocated a 127GB virtual disk to the VM, thinking it could take up all the room on the drive. What I forgot to account for is the disk space required by the 3 VM snapshots I took that are stored on the same physical drive. Now there is 0 space left on the drive and the VM won't run.

What I'd like to do is free up space on the physical drive by deleting all the snapshots. Unfortunately, when I try to delete the snapshot I get an error:

```
Failed to perform an online medium merge (VERR_DISK_FULL)
```

That's when the VM is on but paused. If I force power-off the VM and attempt the merge I get:

```
Failed to delete the snapshot SomeSnapshot of the virtual machine somevm.
Could not merge the medium '/var/vms/somevm/Snapshots/{58220add-b745-4d38-874b-c788f0e31560}.vdi' to '/var/vms/somevm/Snapshots/{181dd674-a65a-44af-afa4-d7ee00cf6c21}.vdi' (VERR_DISK_FULL).
```

What's the easiest way to get out of this mess? The host OS is running Linux Mint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate, hate, hate messing with VirtualBox's arcane media registry system... releasing disks and trying to re-attach snapshots and all that nonsense, so I did it in the simplest way I could think of: copy the VM disk images over to a bigger drive, mount the drive **at the original path of the VM**, re-run the snapshot delete commands, then finally copy the final, smaller disk image back to the original drive. All the gory details follow:

1. Since I use LVM, I first create a new LV to hold the files:

   ```
   sudo lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n vm-resize somevg
   sudo cryptsetup create vm-resize /dev/mapper/somevg-vm--resize --key-file /dev/urandom
   sudo mkfs.ext4 -m 1 /dev/mapper/vm-resize
   ```
2. Next I copy the VM disk images over to the new LV:

   ```
   cd /var/vms
   sudo mkdir vm-resize
   sudo mount /dev/mapper/vm-resize vm-resize/
   sudo cp -a somevm/* vm-resize/
   ```
3. Then I mount the new LV at the same path my SSD was mounted at:

   ```
   umount somevm/ vm-resize/
   sudo mount /dev/mapper/vm-resize somevm/
   ```
4. Finally I can "delete" all the snapshots (which merges them into the current disk image):

   ```
   snapshots=( $(VBoxManage snapshot somevm list | sed -E 's/.*(\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}).*/\1/') )
   for uuid in "${snapshots[@]}"; do
       VBoxManage snapshot somevm delete "$uuid"
   done
   ```
5. But we're not done yet: next I re-mount my two LVs at their original location:

   ```
   sudo umount somevm/
   sudo mount somevm/
   sudo mount /dev/mapper/vm-resize vm-resize/
   ```
6. Then we need to move the new, smaller disk image back to the original drive:

   ```
   sudo rm somevm/Snapshots/*.vdi
   sudo cp -a vm-resize/somevm.vdi somevm/somevm.vdi
   ```

   At this point you want to test the VM to make sure it works.
7. Then finally (for real this time), perform clean up:

   ```
   sudo umount vm-resize
   sudo cryptsetup remove vm-resize
   sudo lvremove somevg/vm-resize
   ```

So easy, right?